# Get the database fields programmatically in Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a jrxml file (sample shown below) which has the database query embedded in it. Now this query will return different columns against different databases. Since the columns are varying, I am planning to programmatically load the jrxml file, read the fields returned from the query (embedded in jrxml) and then place them on the jrxml

Have 2 questions

1. How do I get the field names returned from the query (embedded in jrxml)
2. How do we iterate through those fields so that they can be placed on the jrxml

Amy sample code would be appreciated.

Please note my preference is to use Jasper API's only.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How do you intend to query the database if you do not know the column names? The only case I can think of is that you are always going to select all the columns.

What I think you need is a parameterized query which will allow you to pass column names as parameters. See [this page on using report parameters](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-parameters).

If you really want to always select all the table columns then before filling the report you will have to retrieve the table metadata and pass the column names to the report as parameters. If you are using JDBC then you simply need to call `java.sql.Connection.getMetaData()` and query the MetaData object for column names. However, hardcoding `SELECT *`  is potentially dangerous because your result sets will keep growing in size as new columns get inserted into the table.